# How to sign XML with Java in fastest way possible

Tags: java, oracle11g

need some tips/advice about (optimization) and how to sign XML with a certificate in the fastest way possible. On some databases (Oracle) it needs 30 msec to sign a file.. But on another database, it needs 1.2 sec. This function/method is called in a loop. It signs some XML data and returns a signed XML in a String. (Java method is exposed as PL/SQL function).

```
public static String signXML(String vhodniXml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    dbFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document doc =  dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(vhodniXml.getBytes()));

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("fu:BusinessPremiseRequest");
    Node node = nl.item(0);
    ((Element) node).setIdAttribute("Id", true);

    Enumeration e = p12.aliases();
    String alias = (String) e.nextElement();

    Key privateKey = p12.getKey(alias, geslo.toCharArray());

    KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry
            = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) p12.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(geslo.toCharArray()));

    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    final XMLSignatureFactory sigFactory = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");
    // Create a Reference to the enveloped document
    Reference ref = sigFactory.newReference("#data",
            sigFactory.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA256, null),
            Collections.singletonList(sigFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)),
            null,
            null);

    SignedInfo si = sigFactory.newSignedInfo(sigFactory.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null), sigFactory.newSignatureMethod("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256", null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

    // Create a KeyValue containing the RSA PublicKey
    KeyInfoFactory keyInfoFactory = sigFactory.getKeyInfoFactory();
    X509IssuerSerial x509IssuerSerial = keyInfoFactory.newX509IssuerSerial(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName(), cert.getSerialNumber());

    List x509Content = new ArrayList();

    x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
    x509Content.add(x509IssuerSerial);

    KeyValue keyValue = keyInfoFactory.newKeyValue(publicKey);
    X509Data xd = keyInfoFactory.newX509Data(x509Content);

    // Create a KeyInfo and add the KeyValue to it
    KeyInfo keyInfo = keyInfoFactory.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

    // Create a DOMSignContext and specify the RSA PrivateKey and
    // location of the resulting XMLSignature's parent element
    DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(
            privateKey,
            node
    );

    // Create the XMLSignature (but don't sign it yet)
    XMLSignature signature = sigFactory.newXMLSignature(si, keyInfo);

    // Marshal, generate (and sign) the enveloped signature
    signature.sign(dsc);

    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Transformer trans = TransformerFactory.newInstance()
            .newTransformer();
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));

    return new String(os.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is to remove some IO operations by storing your key related objects in fields because reading the KeyStore to get keys takes time.

Comment: Have moved KeyStore handling outside the method. The execution time is now from 1 sec to 800 msec.. It's almost 4 times slower than on other databases.

Comment: Have debugged each statement in my method and notice that 8xx msec is used with signature.sign(dsc);

Comment: to go deeper, you can use profiler like jProfiler in order to understand where th time is spent.

Comment: The time of 840 msec is "spent" in signature.sign(dsc). "signature" is javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature.

Comment: "sign" is complex, with a profiler you can see where it spends time. It could be cacheable lookup or trivial things you missed.

Comment: I made a test on my machine : signXML took 495ms ( DocumentBuidlerFActory 148ms, XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance 94ms, Transformer.transform 50ms, XMLSignature.sign 46ms  ,KeyStore.load : 35ms)

Comment: In my case I have 3 database servers running Oracle database 11. On two of them the process of signing xml with Java finish in 30-70 msec. On third one I have problems because the process is 4-5 times slower :) So here is the problem because I can't locate why the process of signing xml is slower. We have opened a service request to Oracle support but we don't get any feedback on how to solve. Thank BluEOS for your tests.